# Building Mac OS app - Hide files from 'Contents' folder

Tags: xcode, cocoa, build

New to cocoa, so I'm probably asking a stupid question. When I build a MAC OS app, I can go view package contents, and under Resources I can see my nib files. Now, when I go and see contents of other apps, I don't see their nibs - like Chrome - don't see them! So, is there a way to build your app so so that certain files (nibs, .py files) can't be visible under Contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All files will be visible under Contents - I think that Chrome does not use nibs  as it is cross platform and constructs its GUI directly from code.